# Changing bases of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following problem:

Let L:$R^4->R^3$ be defined by L([$u_1$ $u_2$ $u_3$ $u_4$])=[$u_1$ $u_2 +u_3$ $u_3 + u_4$]

Let S and T be the natural bases for $R^4$ and $R^3$ respectively.

Let S'={[$1, 0, 0, 1$]; [$0, 0, 0, 1$]; [$1, 1, 0, 0$]; [$0, 1, 1, 0$]}

T'={[$1, 1, 0$]; [$0, 1, 0$]; [$1, 0, 1$]}

a)Find the transition matrix P from S' to S

b)Find the transition matrix from S to S' and verify that it is $P^{-1}$

Now for part a I solved it correctly and the answer would be just the matrix which has elements of S' as its columns but for part b why would the answer be $P^{-1}$ and not simple the matrix which has elements of S as it's columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition matrix $P$ from $S'$ to $S$ is the matrix such that, for each $v\in\Bbb R^4$, if $v=[a_1\ \ a_2\ \ a_3\ \ a_4]_{S'}$ (that is, if the coordinates of $v$ with respect to the basis $S'$ are $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, and $a_4$), then $P.v=[b_1\ \ b_2\ \ b_3\ \ b_4]_S$. In particular, $P.[1\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0]$ is the first vector of $S'$, $P.[0\ \ 1\ \ 0\ \ 0]$ is the second vector of $S'$ and so on. That's why the entries of the $i$<sup>th</sup> column of $P$ are the coordinates of the $i$<sup>th</sup> element of $S'$.

The same argument *doesn't* lead to the conclusion that the transition matrix from $S$ to $S'$ is such that the entries of its $i$<sup>th</sup> column of are the coordinates of the $i$<sup>th</sup> element of $S$. And it is only natural that the transition matrix from $S$ to $'$ is the inverse of the transition matrix from $S'$ to $S$, since it performs the inverse operation (this is not a proof, of course).

Comment: I do think it's logical for the inverse operation to use the inverse of the transition matrix but what confuses me is that what if part a was "Find the transition matrix P from S to S' ", wouldn't we have used the elements of S instead? It's still kind of confusing for me, sorry.

Comment: Keep in mind that $S$ is a special basis, because when talk about, say, the vector $v=[1\ \ 3\ \ -2\ \ -4]$, then $v=[1\ \ 3\ \ -2\ \ -4]_S$. So, in order to apply the same method to find the transition matrix from $S$ to $S'$, we would have to write first the vectors of $S$ as linear combinations of elements of $S'$ and then, yes, the coefficients of those linear combinations will be the entries of the transition matrix. For instance,$$[1\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0]=[1\ \ -1\ \ 0\ \ 0]_{S'}$$and therefore the entries of the first column of that transition matrix will be $1$, $-1$, $0$, and $0$.

Comment: thank you, all clear now.